# Как на сервере node js создать файл с расширением JS и засунуть туда готовый объект

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня есть функция которая берет из папки все заголовки файлов и создает массив `var musicName =[]` и вот в этом массиве у меня хранятся все заголовки.

Как мне теперь создать файл JS и записать туда этот массив?

Вот эта функция

```
function getFilesName(dir, files_) {
var musicName = [];

    files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for (let i in files) {
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(name, files_);
        } else {
            files_.push(name);
            musicName = files_;
        }
    }
    console.log(musicName);
    return musicName;
};

getFilesName('./binary/sounds/music/')
```

[image: и итоге в консоли сервера я получаю этот результат из фото.]

Как мне создать js файл и записать туда результат?

Пытался использовать метод `FS.writeFile` - не получилось

Comment: что не получилось с fs.writeFile? и почему вы в js пытаетесь массив сохранить? В json же надо

Comment: Дмитрий ответил хорошо, скорее всего вы что-то не так делали, без ошибки или кода сохранения непонятно. + для прав добавить ключ '{ flag: 'w+' }' перед колбеком если будет ошибка доступа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так

```
var fs = require('fs');

//...ВАШ КОД ВЫШЕ

var arrayString = getFilesName('./binary/sounds/music/');

fs.writeFile("song.js", `var arr = ${JSON.stringify(arrayString)};`, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

На выходе, в файле song.js будет

`var arr = ["song 1 - test", "поля из массива"...]`

Comment: В коде вызывается метод записи строки в файл, при вызове которого он перезаписывает файл, будь то js или txt) 
Когда вы запускаете сервер командой node server.js - у вас вся программа запускается 1 раз, перезаписывается файл с песнями и всё, сервер остается работать.
А когда вы запускаете командой nodemon server.js - то запускается  вотчер, трекер, который реагирует на изменения JS файлов(но не реагирует на изменение TXT файлов) и при наличии их - перезапускает сервер. А при каждом перезапуске сервера перезаписывается файл. 
Странно, что у вас не перезаписывался txt файл, а js - да. хм..